# Пунктуация: "Но самое главное там он найдёт свое счастье"

Tags: пунктуация

Какие знаки препинания тут должны стоять?

"Но самое главное там он найдёт свое счастье"

Comment: А какие бы Вы поставили? Здесь домашнее задания не делают, но могут помочь, если сами начнете - и объясните, в чем проблема.

Comment: Я думаю, что предложение должно выглядеть примерно таким образом:  "Но, самое главное, - там он найдет свое счастье"

И это совсем не домашнее задание

Comment: Вы точку в конце забыли ещё, Егор.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Почему-то мне всегда не нравилось словосочетание ***самое главное.*** Плеоназм налицо.

Возможны варианты представленного вами предложения.

***Но самое главное - там он найдёт свое счастье.***
Самое главное - это подлежащее. Сказуемое, как это ни странно,  выражено целым предложением. Вообще-то сказуемое должно быть выражено указательным местоимением ТО, ср.:*Но самое главное - ТО, ЧТО там он найдёт свое счастье*. Но так как местоимение ТО  выпущено, роль сказуемого играет целое предложение, его заменяющее. Интересно на этот счёт выслушать мнение коллег.

Но, ***самое главное***, там он найдёт своё счастье. Здесь ***самое главное*** - вводное словосочетание. Лучше, конечно,  просто *главное*. Выделяем запятыми.